# Insert new row based on the cell text in column C

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a blank row if the cell values under column C is "Confirm". Is this possible?
I want the macro to add blank rows below until the last active row of the sheet if it finds "Confirm" under column C.

regards,
Arjun T A

Comment: try recording your manual process with the macro recorder so a least you have some code to start with and have a look there : [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. If no effort is shown the community might close or down-vote your question. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Try my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Edited.

```
Dim x As Long, lRow As Long

lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = lRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(x, 3).Value = "Confirm" Then
            With Cells(x, 3).Offset(1).EntireRow
                .Insert Shift:=xlDown
                .ClearFormats
            End With
        End If
    Next x
```

Comment: I don't want the new rows to carry the same format/formulas as the row above

Comment: It is just adding a blank rows after finding the the text for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub blankAfterConfirm()

    Dim rng As Range, fnd As Range, addr As String

    With Worksheets("sheet3").Range("C:C")
        Set rng = .Find(what:="confirm", After:=.Cells(1), MatchCase:=False, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            addr = rng.Address(0, 0)
            Set fnd = rng
            Do
                Set fnd = Union(fnd, rng)
                Set rng = .FindNext(After:=rng)
            Loop Until addr = rng.Address(0, 0)

            fnd.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```